# Check and uncheck checkbox depending on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown. Selection change of a dropdown old checkbox will be unchecked and new checkbox will be checked. How do I it using jquery?

Data is coming from database.

I have this code

```js
$("#roles").change(function() {

      $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("GetPermissionForSelectedRole", "home")',
          type: "get",
          cache: false,
          data: {
            RoleId: roleid
          },
          success: function(alldata) {
            debugger;
            $.each(alldata, function(key, value) {
                debugger;
                var aa = value.Modelid;
                var bb = value.Actionid;
                var abc = aa + '-' + bb;
                var allcheckboxdata = [];
                $("input:checkbox[name=chkboxsecond]").each(function() {
                  allcheckboxdata.push($(this).attr('data-controllername'));
                })
                $.each(allcheckboxdata, function(ab, alchkbox) {
                    debugger;
                    var aabb = alchkbox;
                    if (abc === aabb) {
                      $('input:checkbox[data-controllername="' + abc + '"]').attr('checked', true);
                    })
                })
            }
          });
      });
```

This is my checkbox html code--

```
@foreach (var data in ViewBag.allmodel) {
 <tr>
   <td class=@data.Id>@data.Controller_Name</td>
   @foreach (var ac in ViewBag.AllAction) { 
   <td>
     <div class="checkbox"> 
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" class="allchkbox" 
          data-controllername="@data.Id-@ac.Id" 
          name="chkboxsecond" value=@data.Id>
       </label> 
     </div>
   </td>
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML with the select and the checkbox. What is the result from the server that determines which checkbox to access? You can select all checked boxes using `$("input:checkbox[name=chkboxsecond]:checked")` and uncheck them

Comment: Please show HTML. There is no need to show server code. Show the rendered HTML! Also indent 4 spaces for formatting, not 20 tabs

Answer (score 0):

Not having a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play with, I assume you want to do this:

```js
$("input:checkbox[name=chkboxsecond]").each(function() {
  this.checked = $(this).data("controllername") == abc;
})
```